# django: filter by value in current row

Tags: django, django-queryset

I wasn't quite sure how to word this question so my apologies if it doesn't quite make sense.

Consider the following example

```
id | rowA | rowB
----------------
1  | 3    | 1
2  | 3    | 2
3  | 3    | 3
4  | 3    | 4
5  | 3    | 5
```

Is there a way to query it so I can get the rows where rowA >= rowB ?

Ideally it would return id's 1,2,3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Model.objects.filter(rowA__gte=F('rowB'))
```

You can refer to the columns of the table themselves for comparison. You should read up [ORM docs on the `F` object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)